# display a long text inside a textblock on two lines

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, textblock

I have a listbox which contains a textblock and an image. I want if the text is too long it goes to a second line. At the moment only have of the text is visible. Here is my XAML

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding imgurl}" MaxHeight="120" MaxWidth="120" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="50,0,12,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Could anybody help me?

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking I may be misunderstanding, but is this just an instance that calls for `TextWrapping="Wrap"` on the TextBlock?

Comment: @ChrisW. I've edited a screenshot of what the problem is. I hope you better understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ya, so I guess it is as simple as it looked. You just need to restrict the width of where your text is and invoke `TextWrapping`, which you have multiple options to accomplish that. Here's a couple possibilities...

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding imgurl}" MaxHeight="120" MaxWidth="120" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="50,0,12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Self}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or you could have a panel do it which should get restricted by its parent...

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding imgurl}" MaxHeight="120" MaxWidth="120" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="50,0,2,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or depending on how this ListBox is layed out as a child, it could possibly even be as easy as just adding `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to the TextBlock and then setting the `MaxWidth` on the ListBox itself. Either way, hope this helps... :)

Comment: Okay thank you so much! I'm new to windows phone development. And it's hard to find good documentation.

Comment: @StefGeelen no worries, we've all been there at some point. Glad to help. :)